# Voronoi structure for printing without big overhang

Tags: 3d-printing

I would like to make a "Voronoi" of a mesh and then 3d print it. So I need to have overhangs with less than 45 degree to be able to print it without supports. Does anyone know how can I make it? So far I can only make Voronoi versions of this mesh and only modify "manually" the overhangs, and so it's very ugly.

Example of Voronoi mesh on which I adjusted manually the overhangs:

[image]

Comment: Hi. I suggest adding pictures of what you need/have. Thanks.

Comment: I just added a picture. Hope it will help

Comment: obviously, it didn't